# Synthetic data generation - GANs vs Simulator?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, simulation, generative-models, gan

For synthetic data generation, does the GAN perform better than a simulator? If so, what are the limitations of the simulator?

If we consider Conditional GANs, we could generate data based on the condition provided to CGAN. So, in this case, is it still better to use GANs instead of a simulator?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is ill-posed: what kind of simulation are we talking here? For some applications, simulations need to be precise. Neural networks are, at the core, approximations. A GAN might not be able to give you the level of precision required for the application. For other applications, they can easily beat simulations, specially when it's actually very hard to simulate.

Comment: @Firebug Yes, I agree with that. My question is, If I already have a existing dataset and I want to generate more samples, what would be a better approach/model to use? Is it simulator or a GAN?  When you say, "for other applications, they can easily beat simulations", which applications are you referring to here?